# What is the orthogonal basis for QR factorization?

Tags: linear-algebra

[image]

Since Q has the orthonormal columns of A would the basis be just the columns of Q and the complement be the null space of Q? Would I need to multiply Q by the R matrix? To determine the least square solution I would need to set up the equation Rx = Q transpose * B where b is given by A * x

Comment: While the column space of $A$ is the column space of $Q$, you need to do a little work to produce the orthogonal complement $\operatorname {Col}(A)^\perp $.

Comment: I wouldn't have to deal with the matrix R would i